# UISearchBar cancel button color?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar, background-color, uibarbuttonitem

When I drop a UISearchBar into my view inside Interface Builder, and change its style to Black Opaque, the cancel button stays unfittingly blue / gray and doesn't become black.

How can I make the cancel button black?

EDIT: It does work like this:

```
// Assume a UISearchBar searchBar.
NSArray *subviews = [searchBar subviews];

// The index depends on how you configure the searchBar.
UIButton *cancelButton = [subviews objectAtIndex:3];

// Set the style to "normal" style.
[cancelButton setStyle:0];
```

But the `setStyle:` method is from a private framework, so this might be an issue when submitting the app to Apple.

Comment: instead of using [canelButton setStyle:0] use cancelButton.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];

Answer (score 120):

I used some thing like this and worked with me:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

it changed the cancel button color to black.

**Update** for iOS 9.0, the method `appearanceWhenContainedIn` is deprecated, use `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses` instead:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

And in Swift 3:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.black
```

Comment: Deprecated in iOS 9: [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn:). Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136874/appearancewhencontainedin-in-swift/27807417#27807417

Comment: Not really working on iOS 9. The button color stays the same.

Comment: What's with this up vote madness? Set `tintColor`, job done

Comment: @AdamWaite tintColor changes both the cursor and "Cancel" button color.

Comment: @ChaitanyaShah just set the searchBar tintColor to the desired "Cancel" button color, and UITextField's appearanceWhenContainedIn... to another color

Comment: Swift 3: UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.black

Comment: This is not working if set after creating instance of UISearchBar

Answer (score 36):

The problem with your solution is that the code is assuming that the objectAtIndex:3 is the cancel button. Not only does this generate a compiler warning, but also if you are displaying the Cancel button programmatically (for example using `[searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES]`, you risk crashing the application.

A simpler solution is to set the style of the whole search bar in ViewDidLoad(), using:

```
searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3 alpha:1.0];
```

this overrides the style set in the Interface Builder BUT also changes the colour of the Cancel button to be same colour as the whole bar (although it doesn't let you set the style of Cancel button independently, unfortunately.

Comment: We can also change the color of the cancel button independently irrespective of the color of the searchbar.       searchBar=[[UISearchBar   alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,346,300,0)];
        searchBar.tintColor=[Reusables SKColorFromHexString:@"#505a62"];
        searchBar.delegate=self;
        searchBar.showsCancelButton=YES;
        NSArray *subviews = [searchBar subviews];
        // The index depends on how you configure the searchBar.
        UIButton *cancelButton = [subviews objectAtIndex:2];
        cancelButton.tintColor=[UIColor lightTextColor];

Answer (score 9):

Try this and see: (I tested below code with Swift 4.1 - [Xcode 9.3-beta4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529782/xcode-download/46785627#46785627))

```
@IBOutlet weak var sbSearchBar: UISearchBar!

sbSearchBar.showsCancelButton = true
sbSearchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
sbSearchBar.tintColor = UIColor.red

if let buttonItem = sbSearchBar.subviews.first?.subviews.last as? UIButton {
    buttonItem.setTitleColor(UIColor.yellow, for: .normal)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I think you should use `first(where:)` to find the `UINavigationButton`

```
if let cancelItem = searchBar.subviews.first?.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIButton }) as? UIButton {
      cancelItem.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 4.2

```
let appearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
appearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(named: "goldColor")!], for: .normal)
```

This works for me. Thanks @Tim Semple

Answer (score 6):

for iOS 10:

```
UISearchBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red //cancel button color
UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue //background button color
```

Comment: Putting this in `AppDelegate.application()` sets it globally for your app, which is perfect for me.  Simple and effective.

Answer (score 4):

This is an updated version of [Hossam Ghareeb's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15791136/6697903) for Swift 3:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self] ).tintColor = UIColor.red
```

But this will not override appearance if it has already been set elsewhere for UIBarButtonItem.

For example, in my navbar controller I had to change this:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

To this for the solution above to work:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self] ).setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Came up with a following solution and it is working on iOS 13.0 and iOS 12.4 as well, must be working on prior versions to till iOS 9.0. The following solution is for:

1. Cancel Button Color (Normal State).
2. Cancel Button Color (Disabled State).
3. Search Bar Text Field Background Color (Normal State).

For Objective C:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The above code also fixed my UI issues for iOS 13 and iPhone X.
I included this code in my **AppDelegate.m** class in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function, so that the changes could be done in the whole app.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken **Benjamin's** answer and combined it with safe `Array` lookup to produce a short, but *safe functional* version:

```
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
(searchController.searchBar.subviews[safe: 0]?.subviews as? [UIView])?
    .filter({$0.isKindOfClass(UITextField)})
    .map({$0.tintColor = .lightGrayColor()})
```

This results in coloring the Cancel button white and the cursor when typing gray. Otherwise it would be white and thus not seen. The `searchController` is an object of type `UISearchController`. If anybody wants to use it inside the results controller, replace it with `self`.

The implementation of the `safe:` subscript is **[nkukushkin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329186/safe-bounds-checked-array-lookup-in-swift-through-optional-bindings/30593673#30593673)** answer:

```
extension Array {
    subscript(safe index: Int) -> T? {
        return indices(self) ~= index ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Click on Search bar and set the **tint** color under view from Interface Builder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
let view: UIView = self.searchBar.subviews[0] as UIView
let subViewsArray = view.subviews

for subView: UIView in subViewsArray {
    if let cancelButt = subView as? UIButton{
        cancelButt.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)         
    }
}
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to reproduce the same behavior in Swift :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let view: UIView = self.searchBar.subviews[0] as! UIView
    let subViewsArray = view.subviews

    for (subView: UIView) in subViewsArray as! [UIView] {
        println(subView)
        if subView.isKindOfClass(UITextField){
            subView.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }
    }

}
```