# Safe (bounds-checked) array lookup in Swift, through optional bindings?

Tags: xcode, swift

If I have an array in Swift, and try to access an index that is out of bounds, there is an unsurprising runtime error:

```
var str = ["Apple", "Banana", "Coconut"]

str[0] // "Apple"
str[3] // EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
```

However, I would have thought with all the optional chaining and *safety* that Swift brings, it would be trivial to do something like:

```
let theIndex = 3
if let nonexistent = str[theIndex] { // Bounds check + Lookup
    print(nonexistent)
    ...do other things with nonexistent...
}
```

Instead of:

```
let theIndex = 3
if (theIndex < str.count) {         // Bounds check
    let nonexistent = str[theIndex] // Lookup
    print(nonexistent)   
    ...do other things with nonexistent... 
}
```

But this is not the case - I have to use the ol' `if` statement to check and ensure the index is less than `str.count`.

I tried adding my own `subscript()` implementation, but I'm not sure how to pass the call to the original implementation, or to access the items (index-based) without using subscript notation:

```
extension Array {
    subscript(var index: Int) -> AnyObject? {
        if index >= self.count {
            NSLog("Womp!")
            return nil
        }
        return ... // What?
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize this is slightly OT, but I also feel it would be nice if Swift had clear syntax for performing any sort of bounds check, including lists. We already have a suitable keyword for this, in. So for instance, if X in (1,2,7)... or if X in myArray

Comment:  Be aware that most solutions below 1) use `indices.contains` which is O(n) –thus, terribly inefficient for arrays, and 2) disregard the case where you are actually storing nil objects.

Comment: I ran some comparisons on an array with 10 million complex objects using @nikita's `indices.contains`  (O(n)) and @zubko's bound checking with `return index >= startIndex && index < endIndex` (O(1)). On an iPhone 11, the O(1) solution ran 15x faster than the O(n) solution but they both completed within 1/10 of a millisecond. So yes, the accepted answer is less efficient but the difference is not noticeable. If it's a major concern, I recommend adding an `Array` extension with the same method signature that uses bound checking, and keeping the `Collection` extension that uses `contains`.

Answer (score 856, accepted):

[Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25330930/1607485) has good advice and solution for the question, however, I've happened to stumble on a nicer way of implementing this functionality:

```
extension Collection {
    /// Returns the element at the specified index if it is within bounds, otherwise nil.
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

---

#### Example

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]

for index in -20...20 {
    if let item = array[safe: index] {
        print(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this definitely deserves attention - nice work. I like the included `safe:` parameter name to ensure the difference.

Comment: As of Swift 2 (Xcode 7) this needs a little tweak: `return self.indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil;`

Comment: Swift 2 (Xcode 7) also needs to replace  `-> T?` with `-> Element?`

Comment: In your Swift 2.0 example, I believe that `return count <= index ? nil : self[index]` would also work in place of `return indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil`. Is there a reason to prefer one over the other? The first is more readable to me, since I'm unfamiliar with `~=` and CollectionType's property `indices`.

Comment: The reason is subjective. I read my implementation as "array's indices include index". It's concise, and, to me, seems simpler than a bounds check made of comparisons. I also like to play with new API. You can freely replace my implementation with yours, however you may also want to add a check for negative indexes to be completely `safe`.

Comment: Hey, I've updated the answer for Swift 3. I'll be stuck with Swift 2 for a while longer, so if anything breaks, feel free to point it out.

Comment: To merge all code, you can use #if swift(>=3.0) #else #endif to have all in one file and be ready for your futur Swift upgrade ;)

Comment: Regarding the Swift 3 version: possibly a corner-case-only-prompt, but a prompt nonetheless: there are cases where the "safe" subscript version above isn't safe (whereas the Swift 2 version was): for `Collection` types where the `Indices` are not contiguous. E.g. for `Set` instances, if we were to access a set element by index (`SetIndex<Element>`), we can run into runtime exceptions for indices that are `>= startIndex` and `< endIndex`, in which case the safe subscript fails (see e.g. [this contrived example](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/85398f9d3d5bfc9757905b499d79e26f)).

Comment: @dfri Good point. I think this would work as a more complete Swift 3 version: https://gist.github.com/JJC1138/501ef8186cab49a8f780c2345cff94e7

Comment: @JonColverson yes, that should be safe even for corner cases, noting however that we loose the `O(1)` random index access (which we did, however, also for the `contains` Swift 2 version above), which shouldn't be an issue, however, unless working in some HPC application with huge arrays. For another alternative (similarily `O(n)`), which would correspond to a more direct Swift 2->3 translation of the Swift 2 version above, see [the answer in this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40331858/4573247) (use of `contains` also allows "short-circuiting", as in your explicit `while` loop solution).

Comment: Can someone explain the type constraints for the Swift 3 implementation, and how they were determined?  Without them, Swift tries to use the wrong implementation of `contains()`; it tries to use `contains(where: _)`.  I'm digging through the reference docs to follow along with the (inherited) associated types, and I'm not sure why the provided constraint solves the problem. How did you derive it?

Comment: Shouldn't `safe` be called `unsafe` instead ? I understand that the subscript method itself is safe, but since we're naming the parameter, which is potentially unsafe, it seems odd.

Comment: I don't know if it is also your case, but when I add this, I can't connect the delegate of a tableview in interface builder (the option disappear oddly). I don't know if it is linked.

Comment: Is there a way to override the existent subscript? i.e., call it without the `safe:`

Comment: In my case, Swift4 still crash with "Index out of range"

Comment: To prevent generating indices and iterating over them (O(n)), it's better to use comparisons (O(1)): `return index >= startIndex && index < endIndex ? self[index] : nil`  `Collection` types have `startIndex`, `endIndex` which are `Comparable` . Of course, this won't work for some strange collections which, for example, don't have indices in the middle, solution with `indices` is more general one.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `safe` is not really "safe" in terms of multi-threading, right? It's still possible that `indices.contains(index)` will return `true` but the array will be modified before `self[index]` is called. Maybe it makes sense either to prefer another name for the subscript or add a comment/documentation so the users of the method don't forget about this case.

Comment: @Legonaftik All collections in the Swift Standard Library are value types, so the subscript is operating on a copy of the collection, no changes from another thread can happen between the `indices.contains(index)` and the `self[index]`

Comment: How to get the Line# of the offending statement?

Answer (score 59):

If you really want this behavior, it smells like you want a Dictionary instead of an Array. Dictionaries return `nil` when accessing missing keys, which makes sense because it's much harder to know if a key is present in a dictionary since those keys can be anything, where in an array the key *must* in a range of: `0` to `count`. And it's incredibly common to iterate over this range, where you can be *absolutely sure* have a real value on each iteration of a loop.

I think the reason it doesn't work this way is a design choice made by the Swift developers. Take your example:

```
var fruits: [String] = ["Apple", "Banana", "Coconut"]
var str: String = "I ate a \( fruits[0] )"
```

If you already know the index exists, as you do in most cases where you use an array, this code is great. However, if accessing a subscript could possibly return `nil` then you *have changed the return type* of `Array`'s `subscript` method to be an optional. This changes your code to:

```
var fruits: [String] = ["Apple", "Banana", "Coconut"]
var str: String = "I ate a \( fruits[0]! )"
//                                     ^ Added
```

Which means you would need to unwrap an optional every time you iterated through an array, or did anything else with a known index, just because rarely you might access an out of bounds index. The Swift designers opted for less unwrapping of optionals, at the expense of a runtime exception when accessing out of bounds indexes. And a crash is preferable to a logic error caused by a `nil` you didn't expect in your data somewhere.

And I agree with them. So you won't be changing the default `Array` implementation because you would break all the code that expects a non-optional values from arrays.

Instead, you could subclass `Array`, and override `subscript` to return an optional. Or, more practically, you could extend `Array` with a non-subscript method that does this.

```
extension Array {

    // Safely lookup an index that might be out of bounds,
    // returning nil if it does not exist
    func get(index: Int) -> T? {
        if 0 <= index && index < count {
            return self[index]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

var fruits: [String] = ["Apple", "Banana", "Coconut"]
if let fruit = fruits.get(1) {
    print("I ate a \( fruit )")
    // I ate a Banana
}

if let fruit = fruits.get(3) {
    print("I ate a \( fruit )")
    // never runs, get returned nil
}
```

#### Swift 3 Update

`func get(index: Int) ->`**`T?`** needs to be replaced by `func get(index: Int) ->`**`Element?`**

Comment: +1 (and the accept) for mentioning the issue with changing the return type of `subscript()` to an optional - this was the primary roadblock faced in overriding the default behavior. (I couldn't actually get it to work *at all.*) I was avoiding writing a `get()` extension method, which is the obvious choice in other scenarios (Obj-C categories, anyone?) but `get(` isn't much bigger than `[`, and makes it clear that the behavior may differ from what other developers may expect out of the Swift subscript operator. Thank you!

Comment: To make it even shorter, I use at() ;) Thanks!

Comment: As of Swift 2.0 `T` has been renamed to `Element`. Just a friendly reminder :)

Comment: To add onto this discussion, another reason why bounds checking isn't baked into Swift to return an optional is because returning `nil` instead of causing an exception from an out-of-bounds index would be ambiguous. Since e.g. `Array<String?>` could also return nil as a valid member of the collection, you wouldn't be able to differentiate between those two cases. If you have your own collection type that you know can never return a `nil` value, aka it's contextual to the application, then you could extend Swift for safe bounds checking as answered in this post.

Comment: Works beautifully

Answer (score 45):

To build on Nikita Kukushkin's answer, sometimes you need to safely assign to array indexes as well as read from them, i.e.

```
myArray[safe: badIndex] = newValue
```

So here is an update to Nikita's answer (Swift 3.2) that also allows safely writing to mutable array indexes, by adding the safe: parameter name.

```
extension Collection {
    /// Returns the element at the specified index if it is within bounds, otherwise nil.
    subscript(safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}

extension MutableCollection {
    subscript(safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        get {
            return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
        }

        set(newValue) {
            if let newValue = newValue, indices.contains(index) {
                self[index] = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Extremely underrated answer! This is the correct way tot do this!

Comment: I copied this answer a long time ago and I came back because of 'MutableCollection' being deleted in my project. I can't give you more likes I am afraid!

Answer (score 29):

```
extension Array {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        0 <= index && index < count ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

- O(1) performance
- type safe
- correctly deals with Optionals for [MyType?] (returns MyType??, that can be unwrapped on both levels)
- does not lead to problems for Sets
- concise code

Here are some tests I ran for you:

```
let itms: [Int?] = [0, nil]
let a = itms[safe: 0] // 0 : Int??
a ?? 5 // 0 : Int?
let b = itms[safe: 1] // nil : Int??
b ?? 5 // nil : Int? (`b` contains a value and that value is `nil`)
let c = itms[safe: 2] // nil : Int??
c ?? 5 // 5 : Int?
```

Comment: I think it's up for debate as to whether this is the "correct" way to deal with optionals. I can see `b ?? 5` returning `nil` leading to more bugs than if it returned 5.

Comment: I enhanced the comment in my answer, to clarify the situation: b contains a value and the value is nil. If we casted automatically to `Int?`, we would loose the information, if we got a hit or a miss in the array, which might be necessary in some circumstances. I would rather debate, if Swift could get rid of automatically casting values to optionals (e.g. in comparisons). This is dangerous, because it is silent. If you look for example at Haskell's `Maybe` type and then look at Swift, you would get the feeling, Swift is broken with regards to optionals and its special (non-necessary) syntax.

Comment: count is O(N) performance

Answer (score 22):

### Swift 4

An extension for those who prefer a more traditional syntax:

```
extension Array {
    func item(at index: Int) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need constrain the array elements to equatable to check if the indices contains its index.

Comment: yes - good point - it would only be needed for additional safe methods like deleteObject, etc.

Answer (score 14):

### Valid in Swift 2

Even though this has been answered plenty of times already, I'd like to present an answer more in line in where the fashion of Swift programming is going, which in Crusty's words¹ is: "Think `protocol`s first"

• What do we want to do?
- *Get an Element of an `Array` given an Index only when it's safe, and `nil` otherwise*
• What should this functionality base it's implementation on?
- *`Array` `subscript`ing*
• Where does it get this feature from?
- *Its definition of `struct Array` in the `Swift` module has it*
• Nothing more generic/abstract?
- *It adopts `protocol CollectionType` which ensures it as well*
• Nothing more generic/abstract?
- *It adopts `protocol Indexable` as well...*
• Yup, sounds like the best we can do. Can we then extend it to have this feature we want?
- *But we have very limited types (no `Int`) and properties (no `count`) to work with now!*
• It will be enough. Swift's stdlib is done pretty well ;)

```
extension Indexable {
    public subscript(safe safeIndex: Index) -> _Element? {
        return safeIndex.distanceTo(endIndex) > 0 ? self[safeIndex] : nil
    }
}
```

¹: not true, but it gives the idea

Comment: As a Swift newbie I don't understand this answer. What does the code at the end represent? Is that a solution, and if so, how do I actually use it?

Comment: Sorry, this answer isn't valid anymore for Swift 3, but the process certainly is. The only difference is that now you should stop at `Collection` probably :)

Answer (score 12):

- Because arrays may store nil values, it does not make sense to return a nil if an array[index] call is out of bounds.
- Because we do not know how a user would like to handle out of bounds problems, it does not make sense to use custom operators.
- In contrast, use traditional control flow for unwrapping objects and ensure type safety.

> if let index = array.checkIndexForSafety(index:Int)
>
> ```
>   let item = array[safeIndex: index]
> ```
>
> if let index = array.checkIndexForSafety(index:Int)
>
> ```
>   array[safeIndex: safeIndex] = myObject
> ```

```
extension Array {

    @warn_unused_result public func checkIndexForSafety(index: Int) -> SafeIndex? {

        if indices.contains(index) {

            // wrap index number in object, so can ensure type safety
            return SafeIndex(indexNumber: index)

        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    subscript(index:SafeIndex) -> Element {

        get {
            return self[index.indexNumber]
        }

        set {
            self[index.indexNumber] = newValue
        }
    }

    // second version of same subscript, but with different method signature, allowing user to highlight using safe index
    subscript(safeIndex index:SafeIndex) -> Element {

        get {
            return self[index.indexNumber]
        }

        set {
            self[index.indexNumber] = newValue
        }
    }

}

public class SafeIndex {

    var indexNumber:Int

    init(indexNumber:Int){
        self.indexNumber = indexNumber
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Any reason `SafeIndex` is a class and not a struct?

Answer (score 11):

I realize this is an old question. I'm using Swift5.1 at this point, the OP was for Swift 1 or 2?

I needed something like this today, but I didn't want to add a full scale extension for just the one place and wanted something more functional (more thread safe?). I also didn't need to protect against negative indices, just those that might be past the end of an array:

```
let fruit = ["Apple", "Banana", "Coconut"]

let a = fruit.dropFirst(2).first // -> "Coconut"
let b = fruit.dropFirst(0).first // -> "Apple"
let c = fruit.dropFirst(10).first // -> nil
```

For those arguing about Sequences with nil's, what do you do about the `first` and `last` properties that return nil for empty collections?

I liked this because I could just grab at existing stuff and use it to get the result I wanted. I also know that dropFirst(n) is not a whole collection copy, just a slice. And then the already existent behavior of first takes over for me.

Answer (score 11):

## Swift 5.x

An extension on `RandomAccessCollection` means that this can also work for `ArraySlice` from a single implementation. We use `startIndex` and `endIndex` as array slices use the indexes from the underlying parent `Array`.

```swift
public extension RandomAccessCollection {

    /// Returns the element at the specified index if it is within bounds, otherwise nil.
    /// - complexity: O(1)
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        guard index >= startIndex, index < endIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        return self[index]
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found safe array get, set, insert, remove very useful. I prefer to log and ignore the errors as all else soon gets hard to manage. Full code bellow

```
/**
 Safe array get, set, insert and delete.
 All action that would cause an error are ignored.
 */
extension Array {

    /**
     Removes element at index.
     Action that would cause an error are ignored.
     */
    mutating func remove(safeAt index: Index) {
        guard index >= 0 && index < count else {
            print("Index out of bounds while deleting item at index \(index) in \(self). This action is ignored.")
            return
        }

        remove(at: index)
    }

    /**
     Inserts element at index.
     Action that would cause an error are ignored.
     */
    mutating func insert(_ element: Element, safeAt index: Index) {
        guard index >= 0 && index <= count else {
            print("Index out of bounds while inserting item at index \(index) in \(self). This action is ignored")
            return
        }

        insert(element, at: index)
    }

    /**
     Safe get set subscript.
     Action that would cause an error are ignored.
     */
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        get {
            return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
        }
        set {
            remove(safeAt: index)

            if let element = newValue {
                insert(element, safeAt: index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tests

```
import XCTest

class SafeArrayTest: XCTestCase {
    func testRemove_Successful() {
        var array = [1, 2, 3]

        array.remove(safeAt: 1)

        XCTAssert(array == [1, 3])
    }

    func testRemove_Failure() {
        var array = [1, 2, 3]

        array.remove(safeAt: 3)

        XCTAssert(array == [1, 2, 3])
    }

    func testInsert_Successful() {
        var array = [1, 2, 3]

        array.insert(4, safeAt: 1)

        XCTAssert(array == [1, 4, 2, 3])
    }

    func testInsert_Successful_AtEnd() {
        var array = [1, 2, 3]

        array.insert(4, safeAt: 3)

        XCTAssert(array == [1, 2, 3, 4])
    }

    func testInsert_Failure() {
        var array = [1, 2, 3]

        array.insert(4, safeAt: 5)

        XCTAssert(array == [1, 2, 3])
    }

    func testGet_Successful() {
        var array = [1, 2, 3]

        let element = array[safe: 1]

        XCTAssert(element == 2)
    }

    func testGet_Failure() {
        var array = [1, 2, 3]

        let element = array[safe: 4]

        XCTAssert(element == nil)
    }

    func testSet_Successful() {
        var array = [1, 2, 3]

        array[safe: 1] = 4

        XCTAssert(array == [1, 4, 3])
    }

    func testSet_Successful_AtEnd() {
        var array = [1, 2, 3]

        array[safe: 3] = 4

        XCTAssert(array == [1, 2, 3, 4])
    }

    func testSet_Failure() {
        var array = [1, 2, 3]

        array[safe: 4] = 4

        XCTAssert(array == [1, 2, 3])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
extension Array {
  subscript (safe index: UInt) -> Element? {
    return Int(index) < count ? self[Int(index)] : nil
  }
}
```

Using Above mention extension return nil if anytime index goes out of bound.

```
let fruits = ["apple","banana"]
print("result-\(fruits[safe : 2])")
```

result - nil

Answer (score 1):

I have padded the array with `nil`s in my use case:

```
let components = [1, 2]
var nilComponents = components.map { $0 as Int? }
nilComponents += [nil, nil, nil]

switch (nilComponents[0], nilComponents[1], nilComponents[2]) {
case (_, _, .Some(5)):
    // process last component with 5
default:
    break
}
```

Also check the subscript extension with `safe:` label by Erica Sadun / Mike Ash: http://ericasadun.com/2015/06/01/swift-safe-array-indexing-my-favorite-thing-of-the-new-week/

Answer (score 1):

The "Commonly Rejected Changes" for Swift list contains a mention of *changing* Array subscript access to return an optional rather than crashing:

> Make `Array<T>` subscript access return `T?` or `T!` instead of `T`: The current array behavior is [intentional](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151214/002446.html), as it accurately reflects the fact that out-of-bounds array access is a logic error.  Changing the current behavior would slow `Array` accesses to an unacceptable degree. This topic has come up [multiple](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151214/002425.html) times before but is very unlikely to be accepted.
>
> https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/commonly_proposed.md#strings-characters-and-collection-types

So the basic subscript access will not be changing to return an optional.

However, the Swift team/community does seem open to *adding* a new optional-returning access pattern to Arrays, either via a function or subscript.

This has been proposed and discussed on the Swift Evolution forum here:

https://forums.swift.org/t/add-accessor-with-bounds-check-to-array/16871

Notably, Chris Lattner gave the idea a "+1":

> Agreed, the most frequently suggested spelling for this is: `yourArray[safe: idx]`, which seems great to me. I am very +1 for adding this.
>
> https://forums.swift.org/t/add-accessor-with-bounds-check-to-array/16871/13

So this may be possible out of the box in some future version of Swift. I'd encourage anyone who wants it to contribute to that Swift Evolution thread.

Answer (score 1):

To propagate why operations fail, errors are better than optionals.

```swift
public extension Collection {
  /// Ensure an index is valid before accessing an element of the collection.
  /// - Returns: The same as the unlabeled subscript, if an error is not thrown.
  /// - Throws: `AnyCollection<Element>.IndexingError`
  ///   if `indices` does not contain `index`.
  subscript(validating index: Index) -> Element {
    get throws {
      guard indices.contains(index)
      else { throw AnyCollection<Element>.IndexingError() }
      
      return self[index]
    }
  }
}

public extension AnyCollection {
  /// Thrown when `[validating:]` is called with an invalid index.
  struct IndexingError: Error { }
}
```

```swift
XCTAssertThrowsError(try ["", ""][validating: 2])

let collection = Array(1...10)
XCTAssertEqual(try collection[validating: 0], 1)
XCTAssertThrowsError(try collection[validating: collection.endIndex]) {
  XCTAssert($0 is AnyCollection<Int>.IndexingError)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why no one, has put up an extension that also has a setter to automatically grow the array

```swift
extension Array where Element: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    public subscript(safe index: Int) -> Element? {
        get {
            guard index >= 0, index < endIndex else {
                return nil
            }

            return self[index]
        }

        set(newValue) {
            if index >= endIndex {
                self.append(contentsOf: Array(repeating: nil, count: index - endIndex + 1))
            }

            self[index] = newValue ?? nil
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is easy and works as of Swift 5.1

```swift
var arr:[String?] = ["A","B","C"]

print(arr) // Output: [Optional("A"), Optional("B"), Optional("C")]

arr[safe:10] = "Z"

print(arr) // [Optional("A"), Optional("B"), Optional("C"), nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, Optional("Z")]
```

*Note: You should understand the performance cost (both in time/space) when growing an array in swift - but for small problems sometimes you just need to get Swift to stop Swifting itself in the foot*

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a good idea. It seems preferable to build solid code that does not result in trying to apply out-of-bounds indexes.

Please consider that having such an error fail silently (as suggested by your code above) by returning `nil` is prone to producing even more complex, more intractable errors.

You could do your override in a similar fashion you used and just write the subscripts in your own way. Only drawback is that existing code will not be compatible. I think to find a hook to override the generic x[i] (also without a text preprocessor as in C) will be challenging.

The closest I can think of is

```
// compile error:
if theIndex < str.count && let existing = str[theIndex]
```

**EDIT**: This actually works. One-liner!!

```
func ifInBounds(array: [AnyObject], idx: Int) -> AnyObject? {
    return idx < array.count ? array[idx] : nil
}

if let x: AnyObject = ifInBounds(swiftarray, 3) {
    println(x)
}
else {
    println("Out of bounds")
}
```

Comment: I would disagree - the point of the optional binding is that it only succeeds if the condition is met. (For an optional, it means there is a value.) Using an `if let` in this case does not make the program more complex, nor the errors more intractable. It simply condenses the traditional two-statement `if` bounds check and actual lookup into a single-lined, condensed statement. There are cases (particularly working in a UI) where it is normal for an index to be out of bounds, like asking an `NSTableView` for the `selectedRow` without a selection.

Comment: @Mundi this seems to be a comment, rather than an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @CraigOtis Not sure I agree. You **can** write this check succinctly in a "single-line, condensed statement", e.g. using `countElements` or as the OP did with `count`, just not in the way the language defines writing array subscripts.

Comment: @jlehr Maybe not. It is fair game to question the intention or wisdom of a problem posed.

Comment: @Mundi That's actually a two-liner. (I am the OP, I updated my code to reflect that the lookup is normally part of a variable assignment.) But if you know of a way to combine the bounds check and the lookup in a "single-line, condensed statement", I would be happy to see it - that's what I'm after.

Comment: @CraigOtis Fair enough - let me take a crack at that... How about `if theIndex < str.count && let existent = str[theIndex] {...}`?

Comment: That doesn't compile - you can't include variable binding in an expression in Swift.

Comment: Yeah - I just realized... I will let you know if I find something,

Comment: Check out the edit. Even the function is a one-liner.

Comment: @Mundi Heh, especially if you later edit it to actually answer the question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple extension for array

```
extension Array where Iterator.Element : AnyObject {
    func iof (_ i : Int ) -> Iterator.Element? {
        if self.count > i {
            return self[i] as Iterator.Element
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

it works perfectly as designed

**Example**

```
   if let firstElemntToLoad = roots.iof(0)?.children?.iof(0)?.cNode,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if index >= 0 && index < array.count {
    print(array[index]) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i end up using in my projects

```
import Foundation

extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {

    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        guard index >= startIndex, index < endIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        return self[index]
    }

}

public extension RandomAccessCollection {

    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        guard index >= startIndex, index < endIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        return self[index]
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you only need to *get* values from an array and you don't mind a small performance penalty (i.e. if your collection isn't huge), there is a Dictionary-based alternative that doesn't involve (a too generic, for my taste) collection extension:

```
// Assuming you have a collection named array:
let safeArray = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(0..., array))
let value = safeArray[index] ?? defaultValue;
```

Answer (score -1):

## 2022

infinite index access and safe idx access(returns nil in case no such idex):

```
public extension Collection {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }

    subscript (infinityIdx idx: Index) -> Element where Index == Int {
        return self[ abs(idx) % self.count ]
    }
}
```

but be careful, it will throw an exception in case of array/collection is empty

usage

```
(0...10)[safe: 11] // nil

(0...10)[infinityIdx: 11] // 0
(0...10)[infinityIdx: 12] // 1
(0...10)[infinityIdx: 21] // 0
(0...10)[infinityIdx: 22] // 1
```

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 5** Usage

```
extension WKNavigationType {
    var name : String {
        get {
            let names = ["linkAct","formSubm","backForw","reload","formRelo"]
            return names.indices.contains(self.rawValue) ? names[self.rawValue] : "other"
        }
    }
}
```

ended up with but *really* wanted to do generally like

```
[<collection>][<index>] ?? <default>
```

but as the collection is contextual I guess it's proper.

Comment: How's this answer different from the accepted one? As for me, it looks exactly the same (duplicate).