# Optional vs Bound value assigning var from array

Tags: swift, binding, option-type

I want to check if there is a value in a array and if so assign to a String using a if-left statement:

```
if let scoreValue = scoreValueArray[element!]{
               // do something with scoreValue 
            }
```

> Error: Bound value in a conditional binding must be of optional type

So tried changing the ! to ? but error persists.

Any input appreciated.

scoreValueArray is an array of strings, where a String value is appended to array if a condition is met, then array is saved to NSUserdefaults.

So element is a int which corresponds to a index in the array, bt only if the index is occupied with a String, so

```
scoreValueArray[element!]
```

could return an 'Index out of bounds', hence want to use the if-let.

Comment: Can you provide some context on what exactly `scoreValueArray` is and what `element` is?

Comment: This means scoreValueArray[element!] doesn't return an optional value. You still need to check if your index is less than your array count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what type your `scoreValueArray` is, but for the sake of this answer, I'm going to assume it's an array of `Int`.

```
var scoreValueArray: Array<Int>
```

Now, if we look the definition of the `Array` struct, we'll find this:

```
struct Array<T> : MutableCollectionType, Sliceable {
    // other stuff...

    subscript (index: Int) -> T

    // more stuff
}
```

So, calling the `subscript` method on our array (which is what we do when we say `scoreValueArray`) returns a non-optional.  And non-optionals cannot be used in the conditional binding `if let`/`if var` statements.

We can duplicate this error message in a more simple example:

```
let foo: Int = 3

if let bar = foo {
    // same error
}
```

This produces the same error.  If we instead do something more like the following, we can avoid the error:

```
let foo: Int? = 3

if let bar = foo {
    // perfectly valid
}
```

This is different from a dictionary, whose `subscript` method *does* return an optional (`T?`).  A dictionary will return a value if the key passed in the subscript is found or `nil` if there is no value for the passed key.

We must avoid array-index-out-of-bounds exceptions in the same way we always do... by checking the array's length:

```
if element < scoreValueArray.count {
    scoreValue = scoreValueArray[element]
}
```

Comment: Thanks makes allot more sense, i will try a different approach

Answer (score 3):

Although the accepted answer clearly puts why optional binding is not available in the current implementation, it doesn't provide with a solution.

As it is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329186/safe-bounds-checked-array-lookup-in-swift-through-optional-bindings/30593673), protocols provide an elegant way of safely checking the bounds of an array. Here's the Swift 2.0 version:

```
extension Array {
    subscript (safe index: Int) -> Element? {
        return indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
let fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"]

if let fruit = fruits[safe: 4] {
   // Do something with the fruit
}
```