# Storing Dictionaries in Array ArrayLiterialConversion Error

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am trying to create a array to hold dictionaries.

```
var deaultScoreResults : [Dictionary<String, Int>] = [];
```

But when I try to add a dictionary key:value pair I get:

```
deaultScoreResults.append(["Study Up!", 1]);
```

Error;

> Type 'Dictionary' does not conform to protocol
>   'ArrayLiteralConvertible'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square brackets surrounding a comma separated list of values is an array literal.

```
["this", "is", "a", "swift", "literal", "array"]
```

For a literal dictionary, you need a comma separated list of `key:value` pairs:

```
[1:"this", 2:"is", 3:"a", 4:"swift", 5:"literal", 6:"dictionary"]
```

To fix the error, you simply need to change your comma to a colon:

```
defaultScoreResults.append(["Study Up!":1])
```

However, [based on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422361/optional-vs-bound-value-assigning-var-from-array), I'm going to assume an array of `<String, Int>` dictionaries isn't anywhere near what you're looking for.

I would suggest that you want simply an `<Int, String>` dictionary:

```
var defaultScoreResults = Dictionary<Int, String>()
defaultScoreResults[1] = "Study Up!"
```

Comment: Ha you read my mind that is exactly what I  spent last hour getting my head around, trial and error, cheers again

Comment: So what is the difference bewteen var deaultScoreResults : [Dictionary<String, Int>] = [];  and  var deaultScoreResults = [DictionaryString, Int>] ()?

Comment: @dancingbush in practice, nothing.  They both do the same thing.  I think the latter looks a lot better though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var deaultScoreResults = [Dictionary<String, Int>]()
deaultScoreResults.append(["Study Up!":1])
```

You could also declare it like this:

```
var deaultScoreResults = [[String:Int]]()
```