# Array return optional value?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

For Dictionaries the subscript is declared like this:

```
subscript (key: Key) -> Value?
```

And for Array:

```
subscript (index: Int) -> T
```

I want to do like this with an array:

```
let something = arr[index] ?? somethingElse
```

Is there any existing method to return nil if out of bounds instead of crashing and without having to check for Array count?

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329186/safe-bounds-checked-array-lookup-in-swift-through-optional-bindings

Comment: Yes thats exactly what Im looking for x) Thanks

Comment: It's trivial to write an extension to do this.