# How do I catch "Index out of range" in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would really like to use a more simple classic try catch block in my Swift code but I can't find anything that does it.

I just need:

```
try {
// some code that causes a crash.
}
catch {
// okay well that crashed, so lets ignore this block and move on.
}
```

Here's my dilema, when the TableView is reloaded with new data, some information is still siting in RAM which calls `didEndDisplayingCell` on a tableView with a freshly empty datasource to crash.

So I frequently thrown the exception `Index out of range`

I've tried this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    do {
        let imageMessageBody = msgSections[indexPath.section].msg[indexPath.row] as? ImageMessageBody
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageUploadCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCell
        cell.willEndDisplayingCell()
    } catch {
        print("Swift try catch is confusing...")
    }
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.section)
    print(indexPath.row)

    if msgSections.count != 0 {
        if let msg = msgSections[indexPath.section].msg[indexPath.row] as? ImageMessageBody {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageUploadCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCell
            cell.willEndDisplayingCell()
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very low priority block of code, and I have wasted a lot of time with trial and error figuring out which error handler built into swift works for what seems to be extremely unique situations when I have tons of scenarios just like this one where the code can crash and it will not have any effect on the user experience.

In short, I don't need anything fancy but Swift seems to have extremely specific error handlers that differ based on whether I'm getting a value from a functions return value or getting a value from an array's index which may not exist.

Is there a simple try catch on Swift like every other popular programming language?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: It seems you are trying to fix the wrong problem. You should be solving the problem of why `didEndDisplayCell` is being called on old data after you've reloaded the table view. That doesn't make any sense. Why would that happen? Are you updating the table view's data on a background thread? That would be one possible issue.

Comment: Generally **never** call delegate methods containing `did`, `will` and `should` by yourself. They are called by the framework.

Comment: you have to handle this by checking count of array before acessing by index.

Comment: Have you figured out why was this happening in your case?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As suggested in comments and other answers it is better to avoid this kind of situations. However, in some cases you might want to check if an item exists in an array and if it does safely return it. For this you can use the below Array extension for safely returning an array item.

**Swift 5**

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Generator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
extension Array {
    subscript (safe index: Int) -> Element? {
        return indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

- This way you'll **never hit** `Index out of range`
- You'll have to check if the item is `nil`

refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30593673/2538729) for more

---

> Trying the Swift3 code in a Playground in Xcode 8.3.2 still leads to a
> "crash" when I do let ar = [1,3,4], then let v = ar[5]. Why? – Thomas
> Tempelmann May 17 at 17:40

You have to use our customized subscript so instead of `let v = ar[5]`, it wll be `let v = ar[safe: 5]`.

Default getting value from array.

```swift
let boo = foo[index]
```

Add use the customized subscript.

```swift
let boo = fee[safe: index]

// And we can warp the result using guard to keep the code going without throwing the exception.
guard let boo = foo[safe: index] else {
  return
}
```

Comment: I wish this was the default behavior

Comment: not worked for me. Can you explain how this works and what is ~indices~ in this

Comment: This introduces optionals to contexts when no optionals should be needed. The best solution is to let your app crash. Indexing out of bounds is a sign of programmer error. You shouldn't ignore that sign or try to swallow it with an optional. Just avoid it.

Comment: @Sulthan, Out of bound index may not be due to programming error. For instance you are dealing with dynamic data that you as a programmer have no control over. Language should safeguard the program from ever ever ending in a fetal run time error. It's a sign of bad language design and infancy of Swift compared to other languages. Hope this gets changed in future versions.

Comment: Trying the Swift3 code in a Playground in Xcode 8.3.2 still leads to a "crash" when I do `let ar = [1,3,4]`, then `let v = ar[5]`. Why?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann obviously because the array's maximum index is `2` and you try to access `5`. That returns `nil` and the app crashes due to the lack of the value requested

Comment: There might very well exist occasions where this is not a programming error. (=It worked for me.) Excellent.

Comment: In Swift 5 `Generator.Element?` become `Iterator.Element?`

Comment: @Joannes I've moved on from swift, but in case you were able to get a swift 5 version working, consider editing this existing answer or add a new one.

Answer (score 34):

Swift's [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) (`do`/`try`/`catch`) is **not** the solution to **runtime exceptions** like "index out of range".

A runtime exception (you might also see these called *trap*, *fatal error*, *assertion failure*, etc.) is a sign of programmer error. Except in `-Ounchecked` builds, Swift usually guarantees that these will **crash** your program, rather than continuing to execute in a bad/undefined state. These sorts of crashes can arise from force-unwrapping with `!`, implicit unwrapping, misuse of `unowned` references, integer operations/conversions which overflow, `fatalError()`s and `precondition()`s and `assert()`s, etc. (And, unfortunately, Objective-C exceptions.)

The solution is to simply **avoid these situations**. In your case, check the bounds of the array:

```
if indexPath.section < msgSections.count && indexPath.row < msgSections[indexPath.section].msg.count {
    let msg = msgSections[indexPath.section].msg[indexPath.row]
    // ...
}
```

(Or, as rmaddy says in comments — investigate **why** this problem is occurring! It really shouldn't happen at all.)

Comment: In what circumstances could the following cause an index out of error then? `for i in 0...magnitudes.count-1 { barHeight = magnitudes[i]*maxHeight; }` - I'm getting this randomly in my app, and the magnitudes array isn't being altered in any other threads (that I can see). I also check that the count is more than 0 before this loop, too.

Comment: I'd recommend you ask a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Fair enough. After doing some logging, I found the count value jumps from the expected value (which is only 16), to some obscure number in the billions. I'm thinking its a memory issue so I'll probably just keep at it. Just thought there might be some obvious causes for the count to change without the developer initiating it.

Answer (score 31):

### Swift 4:

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    subscript (exist index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
var index :Int = 6 // or whatever number you need
if let _ = myArray[exist: index] {
   // do stuff
}
```

or

```
var index :Int = 6 // or whatever number you need
guard let _ = myArray[exist: index] else { return }
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Swift 5

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37225027/5941807) answer in **Swift 5** become:

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Otherwise from **Swift 4** there's the ability to have clauses on associated types and it can become:

```
extension Collection {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the array index within the bounds, using below code.

```
guard array.indices.contains(index) else { return }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a different approach to this. Will surely work!

```
if msgSections != nil {
    for msg in msgSections[indexPath.section] {
        if msgSections[indexPath.section].index(of: msg) == indexPath.row {
            (Code)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know most people will go for the top-voted answers but let me post my solution and explain why I did so:

```swift
public extension Collection {
    /**
     Checks the `index` and returns a value if valid.
     - Throws: `GeneralError.illegalArguent`
     */
    func get(index: Index) throws -> Element {
        // Note: GeneralError is a custom error type
        guard indices.contains(index) else { throw GeneralError.illegalArgument }
        return self[index]
    }
    
}
```

1. In Swift nomenclature, the word "safe" conveys a very specific meaning: expected/defined behavior. A quote from [this WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10648/):

> We say that the force unwrap operator is "safe" because we can fully describe its behavior for all possible inputs, including input that doesn't satisfy its requirements.

For situations like these, Swift API tends to use term "checked" as in [CheckedContinuation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/checkedcontinuation). So if I were to go with the `subscript` solution, I would make it so that it looks like: `someList[checked: index]`.

2. This one is more personally biased: I believe optionals should be used only for situations where there really is a nothingness.

For instance, you can search for an element in an `Array` with a predicate and get nothing back because no element matched. This is a legitimate reason to use optionals. However, if a routine cannot continue because a bad input was given, that should result in throwing an error, not an optional return value.

Swift doesn't support throwing subscripts, so I had to resort to using a method.