# Catch all errors, exceptions, no matter what it is, in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and I have a little problem.

I have a piece of code, and any line could potentially throw an error.

My problem is, I don't want to go through line by line catching each error, I want to catch them all in one statement.

In python you can do this

```
try:
    exampleArray = [1,2,3,4]
    print(exampleArray[4])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass
```

What that does is try to print a value from the array that doesn't exist, but it is caught by the `except` statement, I am wondering whether something this easy exists in Swift

To clarify, I am not trying to catch an `index out of range` error, I just want to catch an error, no matter what it is.

Is it possible without declaring my own errors, and throwing them line by line?

Comment: You *cannot* catch a index-out-of-range exception in Swift.

Comment: Related (dupe?): [How do I catch “Index out of range” in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37222811/2976878)

Comment: No you guys don't get the idea, I'm trying to catch all errors, not just that one

Comment: Not all errors in swift are even catchable.

Comment: No, you cannot catch all errors in Swift like that. Swift is quite limited in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift you can only catch errors that are `throw`n.

Since not all errors are handled by `throw`ing (e.g. an out-of-range array access), you cannot catch everything.

Comment: Wouldn't catch be unreachable because of no throw in do?

Comment: @Will If that's the case, yes. The `catch` body is only entered if an error is thrown.

Comment: Yes, just tested and this does not work, if an error occurs in do, app crashes

Comment: `catch` only catches _thrown_ errors, not arbitrary programming errors in the code. Since an out-of-range array access does not `throw` anything, you can't `catch` it.

Comment: The out of range error won't happen, it was an example to show an error

Comment: @SilentDownvoters: Is there something incorrect in the answer?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the question. But it is about catching absolutely all and any error inside the block. Your answer fails to do that. Actually, real answer is Swift is not capable of catching all exceptions like some other languages do.