# Understanding try catch , swift3 xcode

Tags: swift

with swift3 and I want handling one error,

```
public func titulo()
        {do{
            marca.snippet=address_components?[1].short_name
            marca.title = try (address_components?[2].short_name)!+" "+(address_components?[3].short_name)!
            //return titulo
        }catch{
            marca.title="sin titulo"
            }

    }
```

Error call when address_components is nil , but in the debug:

[image]

What I can do , to fix this?

Comment: Related: [How do I catch “Index out of range” in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222811/how-do-i-catch-index-out-of-range-in-swift). The answer is simply you do not catch the runtime error – you prevent it from happening in the first place (i.e [by *safely* unwrapping the optional](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32170456/2976878) and by not indexing out of a collection's bounds).

Answer (score 2):

`try` / `catch` doesn't catch exceptions, only errors thrown. It does nothing to help you avoid crashing when using implicitly unwrapped optionals (!). The warning was a good hint here.

Answer (score 2):

You have two things going on here: 1) the `try/catch`, and 2) force-unwrapping of an optional.

**Update:** <s>The `try/catch` is fine.</s> The code you have inside the `try/catch` actually doesn't `throw`. Therefore, you don't need the `try/catch` there.

An example of something that does `throw` is `FileManager.contentsOfDirectory`. It looks like this in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1413768-contentsofdirectory) (notice the `throws` keyword):

```
func contentsOfDirectory(at url: URL, 
includingPropertiesForKeys keys: [URLResourceKey]?, 
             options mask: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions = []) throws -> [URL]
```

You can make your own functions `throw` as well, but your current code doesn't. That's why you get the `'catch' block is unreachable...` message.

**The second issue is with the optionals.**

An "optional" in Swift is something that could possibly be nil (empty, without a value).

Your code has these two parts: `(address_components?[2].short_name)!` and `(address_components?[3].short_name)!`

The `!` marks are saying that you're CERTAIN that these items won't be nil! (Think of the `!` as telling the system "YES! IT'S NOT NIL!" Likewise, think of the `?` as saying, "Umm, is this empty? Does this have a value?")

As it turns out, one of those values IS nil. Therefore, Swift doesn't know what the heck to do with it. CRASH AND BURN! ;)

So, in addition to your `try/catch`, you're going to need some `guard` statements or `if let` statements somewhere to make sure your values are not nil.

Comment: No, the `do/catch` is not fine since the code inside the `try` doesn't throw.

Comment: And a better description of `!` is "crash if nil". Swift knows just what to do when you are sure it's not nil but wrong.