# Swift: Error ignores try statement

Tags: swift, error-handling, swxmlhash

In my code I'm deserialising some XML using the [SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash) library. Its `.value()` method has the `throws` keyword in its declaration, as do any custom deserialise functions.

I have the following line of code:

```
let myValue : UInt8 = try? xml["Root"]["ValueNode"].value()
```

Since the library doesn't include a deserialiser for `UInt8`, I've defined my own:

```
extension UInt8: XMLElementDeserializable {
    public static func deserialize(_ element: XMLElement) throws -> UInt8 {
        return UInt8(element.text)!
    }
}
```

This works when the node has a value. However, when the node doesn't exist or is nil, an error occurs on the following line:

```
return UInt8(element.text)!  // Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This is supposed to happen, obviously. What I don't understand is why this error is not being caught by my `try?` statement and returning `nil` instead of throwing that error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can't deal with fatal errors using `throws` and `try`, it's fatal. There are proper ways built into Swift to deal with optionals.

Comment: This has been covered quite a few times before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37222884/2976878, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38738365/2976878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46866311/2976878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/31335023/2976878 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/43009744/2976878 to name a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all errors can be caught in Swift. If you mark a function using the `throws` keyword it indicates that the function might throw a *recoverable* error. However, your custom implementation doesn't actually throw any errors. Only errors thrown from functions marked with the `throws` keyword and thrown using the code `throw Error` can be caught by a do-catch block.

`try?` is a way to convert a throwable function's return value to an optional. If the function would throw an error, the value after the `try?` will be `nil`, otherwise it will be an optional value.

When you use the `!`, you specifically tell the compiler that you know what you are doing and if the operation on which you used the `!` fails, your app shouldn't fail gracefully.

You'll need to change your `deserialize` method to handle the optional unwrapping gracefully or throw and error.

```
extension UInt8: XMLElementDeserializable {
    public static func deserialize(_ element: XMLElement) throws -> UInt8 {
        if let val = UInt8(element.text) {
            return val
        } else {
            throw NSError(domain: "Couldn't deserialize value to UInt8", code: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return UInt8(element.text)!
```

There's no `try` in this line. Therefore, no errors are going to be thrown here. If `UInt8` can't convert the string it's given, it just returns `nil`. And then, of course, your `!` turns that `nil` into a crash.

Instead of that, do something like this instead:

```
guard let retVal = UInt8(element.text) else { throw SomeError }
return retVal
```

In general: When there's a way to do something using `!`, and another way to do the same thing without using `!`, go for the second one unless you've got a really good reason.