# Fast way to check if array CAN have an element at given index?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

To prevent potential crashes, whenever I attempt to access a specific element in an array I normally do some safety-checks. I just realised I'm kinda tired of doing that. Is there a way to do it quickly and safely?

```
var array:[String] = [/*Filled with stuff*/]
func someFunc(someIndex:Int){

    //This is unsafe. It will crash if index is negative or larger than count.
    let text = array[someIndex]

    //This is completely safe, but boring.
    let text:String
    if someIndex >= 0 && someIndex < array.count{
        text = array[someIndex] 
    }else { return }

    //What I want is something like this:
    let text = array.hasElement(at: someIndex) ? array[someIndex] : return
    //I know, I can't really put a 'return' in a statement like this, but I really want to..

    //Optimally, I'd like something like this:
    guard let text = array[someIndex] else { return }
    //But this is illegal because it's not an conditional binding with an optional type.
}
```

While writing this I realised I could probably create my own extension of `Sequence` or something, to add a function for `func hasElement(at:Int)->Bool`. But I'd rather want a way to use `guard` since I can't do an inline `condition ? true : return`..

Any one-liners are appreciated..

Comment: Various solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329186/safe-bounds-checked-array-lookup-in-swift-through-optional-bindings and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222811/how-do-i-catch-index-out-of-range-in-swift

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S What if `YourINDEX` is `-3`? A negative number will crash just as much as if index is higher than the number of elements. I already compensated for this in the question. Also, getting a `boolValue` is not at all what I was looking for. I was looking for a *better* way than to *check* this every time.

Comment: @Sti, great :) Since, array's doesn't have negative indices! So, I thought you are using positive `Int`'s only.! lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple enough to do with an extension on `Collection`:

```
extension Collection {
    subscript(checked index: Index) -> Element? {
        if self.indices.contains(index) {
            return self[index]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And so:

```
let arr = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]

print(arr[checked: 2]) // Optional("Baz")
print(arr[checked: 3]) // nil
```

If that's too much, you could just use the ternary operator:

```
let foo: String? = arr.indices.contains(3) ? arr[3] : nil
```

Comment: That's essentially https://stackoverflow.com/a/37225027/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/30593673/1187415 :)

Comment: Well this is almost exactly what I wanted! I completely forgot subscript was a thing, thanks! All we need now is the ability to perform a return-command in the ternary operator (like Kotlin can do with their elvis-operator, as far as I understand)

Comment: @Sti Well, you can kind of, sort of do that, although it's not pretty: `guard let foo: String? = { bar ? baz : nil }() else { /* bail */ }`

Comment: @Sti Or, if your function throws: `let foo = bar ? baz : try { throw someError }()`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way of doing above is.

```
extension Array {
    func haveItem(at index: Index) -> Bool {
         return index < self.count
    }
}

if yourArray.haveItem(at: 4) {
     //You have some item at index 4 in yourArray object.
}
```