# Unable to use indices.contains() in a Collection extension in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2

I wrote following extension in Swift 2.3:

```
extension CollectionType {
    /// Returns the element at the specified index iff it is within bounds, otherwise nil.
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Generator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

However, it turns out that Swift 3.0 does not have `contains()` function. Instead, it offers me following syntax for this method:

```
indices.contains(where: { (<#Self.Indices.Iterator.Element#>) -> Bool in
    <# code ??? what should it do??? #>
})
```

The problem is that I don't know what should it contain inside the block. Any help with migrating it, please?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Swift 4 Update

In Swift 4, thanks to [the ability to have `where` clauses on associated types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md), `Collection` now enforces that [`Indices`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/1786763-indices)'s `Element` type is the same type as the `Collection`'s `Index`.

This therefore means that we can just say:

```
extension Collection {

    /// Returns the element at the specified index iff it is within bounds, otherwise nil.
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

---

#### Swift 3

The `Sequence` protocol in Swift 3 still has a [`contains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641180-contains) method, which accepts an element of the sequence if the sequence is of `Equatable` elements:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : Equatable {
    // ...
    public func contains(_ element: Self.Iterator.Element) -> Bool
    // ...
}
```

The problem you're encountering is due to the change in the type of `Collection`'s `indices` property requirement. In Swift 2, it was of type `Range<Self.Index>` – however in Swift 3, it is of type [`Indices`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/indices) (an associated type of the `Collection` protocol):

```
/// A type that can represent the indices that are valid for subscripting the
/// collection, in ascending order.
associatedtype Indices : IndexableBase, Sequence = DefaultIndices<Self>
```

As there's currently no way in Swift for the `Collection` protocol *itself* to express that `Indices`'s `Iterator.Element` is of type [`Index`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/indexablebase/index) ([this will however be possible in a future version of Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md)), there's no way for the compiler to know that you can pass something of type `Index` into `contains(_:)`. This is because it's currently fully possible for a type to conform to `Collection` and implement `Indices` with *whatever* element type it wants.

Therefore the solution is to simply constrain your extension to ensure that `Indices` *does* have elements of type `Index`, allowing you to pass `index` into `contains(_:)`:

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {

    /// Returns the element at the specified index iff it is within bounds, otherwise nil.
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30593673/1187415 is a solution which does not require any constraints.

Comment: @MartinR Ah yes, I may have overthunk the solution in this case ;) Although once [SE-0142: Permit where clauses to constrain associated types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md) is implemented, I would hope that the stdlib team will add the constraint to the associated type itself, so the extension won't require it.

Comment: A possibly corner-case-only-prompt, but a prompt nonetheless: there are cases where the simplified `O(1)` "safe" subscript version in the linked Q&A is still not entirely safe, whereas the `O(n)` version above, is: for `Collection` with `Indices` that are not contiguous. E.g. for `Set` instances, _if_ we were to access a set element by index (`SetIndex<Element>`), we can run into runtime exceptions for indices that are `>= startIndex` end `< endIndex`, in which case the safe subscript fails (see e.g. [this contrived example](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/85398f9d3d5bfc9757905b499d79e26f)).

Comment: @dfri A very good point, thanks for mentioning it! Although the solution above isn't necessarily O(n) – if the conforming type's `Indices` have an O(1) implementation of `contains(_:)` and the concrete type of the conforming type is known (not type erased), the O(1) implementation should be used (IIRC).

Comment: You're right! I was pondering if the extension in the linked answer should be applied to e.g. `RandomAccessCollection` rather than `Collection` (or some other more appropriate protocol), in which case (I believe) it would be safe, but then it's possibly to narrow instead.

Comment: @dfri Yeah, I don't *believe* there's a protocol out there that guarantees contiguous indices – although you'd have to have a *really* wacky implementation of `RandomAccessCollection` to warrant non-contiguous indices (I suppose one really (I mean *really*) contrived example could be a specialised collection for storing two interleaved collections– a 'just the elements of collection A' *slice* of such a collection could be a `RandomAccessCollection`, but would have non-contiguous indices, as it would be skipping an index upon advancing).

Comment: @Hamish Is contains method faster than using a guard to get the  index offsetBy n limitedBy endIndex and returning nil or is it the same?. `extension Collection {
    subscript(safe offset: Int) -> Element? {
        guard let index = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset, limitedBy: endIndex) else { return nil }
        return self[index]
    }
}`

Comment: Btw why `~=` operator  (I think I read that Apple says it is preferred over contains) cant be used in this case `return indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil`

Comment: @LeoDabus I wouldn't expect there to be any real performance differences between the two – at least if there was, I would consider that to be a bug of the conforming collection rather than a flaw of the subscript's implementation. (Slight tangent: Arguably, this extension should only be written on `RandomAccessCollection` to ensure the check is always done in O(1) time to fit with the semantics of a subscript). Note btw that you'd also need to add the condition `index != endIndex` to your guard, as `limitingBy:` is an inclusive upper bound.

Comment: @LeoDabus Regarding why you can't use `~=`, it's because there's no overload of it that deals with collections. There is an overload however that deals with `RangeExpression`, which is why you can say things like `0 ... 1 ~= 0`. (Though as a point of preference, I always prefer `contains` over `~=`).

Comment: @Hamish Thank you. So the only way would be something like `func ~= <C: Collection>(lhs: C, rhs: C.Element) -> Bool where C.Element: Equatable  {
    return lhs.contains(rhs)
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Yup – and that would also let you do things like `switch 5 { case [1, 2, 5]: ... }`

Comment: @Hamish What about `extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    static func ~= (lhs: Self, rhs: Element) -> Bool   {
        return lhs.contains(rhs)
    }
}` which one do you prefer? I prefer the second one

Comment: @LeoDabus Yup, I prefer the one in the extension

Comment: Hi there, can you take a look [Do protocols have an effect on the retain count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227192/do-protocols-have-an-effect-on-the-retain-count)