# what's the meaning of "Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index"

Tags: swift

I could not figure out the purpose/meaning of "Indices.Iterator.Element == Index" in following code

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {

    /// Returns the element at the specified index iff it is within bounds, otherwise nil.
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Generator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that I have updated [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40331858/2976878), which (I hope) better explains the reasoning behind the constraint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The generic constraint syntax `where T == U` says that the type `T` must be the same type as type `U`.

Let's do a simpler example first:

```
protocol GenericProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    associatedtype U
}

extension GenericProtocol where T == U {
    func foo() {}
}

class ConcreteClassA: GenericProtocol {
    typealias T = Int
    typealias U = Float
}

class ConcreteClassB: GenericProtocol {
    typealias T = Int
    typealias U = Int
}

let a = ConcreteClassA()
let b = ConcreteClassB()
```

Now which of these, `a` or `b` has the member `foo`? The answer is `b`.

Since the extension's generic constraint says that `T` and `U` must be the same type, the extension is only applied to `ConcreteClassB` because its `T` and `U` are both `Int`.

Back to your code now.

In your code, you're saying that `Indices.Iterator.Element` must be the same type as `Index`. Let's figure what these two types are respectively.

`Indices` is the type of the property `indices`. So `Indices.Iterator.Element` is type of each index of the collection. `Index` on the other hand, is the type of value that you can put into the subscript of of the collection. This constraint seems excessive but it is in fact not. I can't think of an example of a type where the constraint is not true. But you can in theory create such a type. That's why the constraint is there.

If the constraint weren't there, this would not compile:

```
indices.contains(index)
```

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it! @Jacky

Comment: Xcode 9 says this is redundant. (with a warning): **Redundant same-type constraint 'Self.Index' == 'Self.Indices.Iterator.Element'**

Comment: @Jonny My answer is for swift 3. Xcode 9 uses swift 4, so it is possible that something is changed.

Answer (score 2):

`contains(_:)` is being called on the `indices` property (which has type `Indices`), with the parameter called `index` (which has type `Index`). The only way this is possible is if the `Indices` elements are of the same type as `Index`.

This constraint is added to assert that this is true, thus allowing the code to compile.

Take `Array` of example. Its `Indices` associated type is set to [`CountableRange<Int>`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/indices) and its `Index` associated type is set to [`Int`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/index). Array is able to conform to your protocol because it's true that the elements of the iterator of `CountableRange<Int>` (`CountableRange<Int>.Iterator.Element`) and the type of `Index` are both `Int`.