# Do protocols have an effect on the retain count?

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, protocols

I have a very simple code. I’m **PURPOSELY** creating a memory cycle with a delegate. Trying to observe and learn how to use Xcode's Memory Graph.

What I don’t get is why in the connections sections, Xcode says there are *3* connections. There should only be 2.

[image]

If I create a memory cycle with with closures, then it will show *2* connections.

My code for leaking with delegate:

```
protocol SomeDelegate {
    func didFinishSomething()
}

class Something {
    var delegate: SomeDelegate?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, SomeDelegate {

    var x = Something()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("view did load")
        x.delegate = self
    }

    func didFinishSomething() {
        print("something was finished")
    }

    deinit {
        print("dellocated!!!")
    }
}
```

I push that view into a navigationController then go back.

The 2 delegate objects have a slightly different memory addresses, it differs just by a `+16`

---

It seems that it has something to do with delegate object being a protocol. Because when I removed the protocol, then it reduced down to **2**:

```
class Something2 {
    var delegate: ViewController?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var x = Something2()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("view did load")
        x.delegate = self
    }

    deinit {
        print("dellocated!!!")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Xcode is just confused – using a protocol value shouldn't cause any extra retains, it should just perform retains like a normal strong reference would.

Comment: It appears to be the optionality that's confusing Xcode – try with https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/26edbfd8531c9c3c49391cfb44c4d9c7, the memory graph now correctly shows 2 connections.

Comment: Thanks. I used your code. Changed `var delegate: SomeDelegate` to `var delegate: SomeDelegate?` and then it shows 2. Is that still what you expected? If it was the optionality then I suppose it should have gone back to 3...

Comment: Huh, I guess it's not the optionality then, must be some other factor. Interestingly enough, in a minimised example run in a command line project, it appears the order in which the assignments are made can affect the result: https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/52c616c7402df2cf23fa781aea19e590. Whatever the underlying cause, I believe that Xcode is at fault here, not Swift.

Comment: Hah! Can you put your snippets in an answer? Thought we haven't arrived at a conclusion, sometimes the answer is "it's faulty"

Comment: Sure I'll write up an answer in a bit – I also just tried setting symbolic breakpoints on `swift_retain` and `swift_release`, and they get called the same number of times. Going to try build swift with `SWIFT_ENABLE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_COUNTERS` set to hopefully verify that other runtime functions also get called the same number of times (and for the same objects).

Comment: Unfortunately wasn't able to learn anything useful from `SWIFT_ENABLE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_COUNTERS` – posted an answer with everything else though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is just Xcode getting confused. A protocol value shouldn't cause any extra retains over a normal strong reference, as memory management operations are forwarded to the underlying value through the type metadata stored within the existential container.

Here's a minimal example that reproduces the same result in Xcode's memory graph debugger:

```
protocol P {}

class C : P {
  var d: D?
}

class D {
  var p: P?
}

func foo() {
  let c = C()
  let d = D()
  c.d = d
  d.p = c
}

foo()

print("insert breakpoint V")

print("insert breakpoint ^")
```

If you insert a breakpoint between the print statements and look at the memory graph, you'll see 3 connections. Interestingly enough, if you assign `c.d` after you assign `d.p`, you'll see the correct result of 2 connections instead.

However if we set symbolic breakpoints on `swift_retain` and `swift_release` in order to see the strong retain/release Swift ARC traffic (while printing out the value stored in the `%rdi` register, which appears to be the register used to pass the argument on x86):

[image]

and then insert a breakpoint immediately after the call to `foo()`, we can see that in both cases the instances each get +2 retained and -2 released (bearing in mind they enter the world as +1 retained, thus keeping them allocated):

```
swift_retain 1
     rdi = 0x000000010070fcd0
swift_retain 2
     rdi = 0x000000010070fcd0
swift_release 1
     rdi = 0x0000000000000000
swift_release 2
     rdi = 0x000000010070fcd0
swift_retain 3
     rdi = 0x00000001007084e0
swift_retain 4
     rdi = 0x00000001007084e0
swift_release 3
     rdi = 0x00000001007084e0
swift_release 4
     rdi = 0x000000010070fcd0
swift_release 5
     rdi = 0x00000001007084e0
```

So it looks like Xcode is at fault here, not Swift.

Comment: As a reference to know what rdi is about: see [Assembly Register Calling Convention Tutoria from RW](https://www.raywenderlich.com/615-assembly-register-calling-convention-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the existential container that is used to implement protocol-typed variables can generate an extra retain. See [Understanding Swift Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/) for various implementation details. 16 bytes (2 machine words) is the header of the existential container.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I'll watch the video and read up on "existential container" and then get back to you. I currently have no clue about these

Comment: I watched the video. I’ll watch it again. It was very interesting. Just didn’t find a mention of existential container, extra retain, machine words. Is there any specific minute that you found more related?

Comment: I'm sorry; the two videos have very similar titles. The correct one is Understanding Swift Performance (updated link)

Comment: I watched parts of the video. I think you're talking about [this moment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/?time=1598). Does this mean there's a heap allocation for any concrete class that has more than 2 properties? btw did you get a chance to see Hamish's answer and comments on the question? He seems to acknowledge what you're saying, but dismisses it.

Comment: My working assumption on anything related to Swift implementation details is that Hamish knows more than I do about it.

Comment: My working assumption on anything related to programming is that you guys know way better than me all the time :). Alrighty thank you