# Can I safely assume that Documents directory always exists on iOS

Tags: ios

There is common pattern for iOS Documents directory retrieval:

```
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
```

However, if `paths` array is empty above code will crash with 'Index out of bounds' error.

Is it safe to assume that Documents directory is always available and that `paths` will always contain at least one entry in above code?

I want to avoid paranoid programming and code sprinkled with unnecessary testing for Documents directory existence.

Comment: There's [this extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30593673/3397217) that handles arrays: you can *safely* get the array's contents at some index. You still have to check whether it is nil though :/

Comment: The Documents folder is always created for you. See the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) to decide whether you should use Documents vs something else (e.g. Caches or something else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the alternative API with the option to create the directory

```
let documentsDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, 
                                                       in: .userDomainMask, 
                                           appropriateFor: nil, 
                                                   create: true)
```

Or today more convenient

```
let documentsDirectory = URL.documentsDirectory
```

Comment: Yes, but in this case `try!` is safe

Comment: Why is the `try!` safe? When it fails in some rare case - boom, the app crashes.

Comment: @rmaddy `Documents` in the user domain is always available respectively can always be created. The `try` is for other failable combinations