# How to transpose a matrix of unequal array length in Swift 3

Tags: multidimensional-array, swift3, padding, transpose

My array is of type [[Int]]

```
array = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9,10],
         [11,12,13],
         [14,15,16]]
```

I want the transpose result as:

```
array = [[1,4,7,11,14],
         [2,5,8,12,15],
         [3,6,9,13,16],
         [0,0,10,0,0]]
```

How to pad 0's to an array which does not have an equal row or column mapping.

I want the transpose to work for both rows and columns with unequal mapping elements. Please help.

Comment: Firstly, I would include a bounds-checked array lookup, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30593673/3151675).

Comment: @the4kman It did not work. Can u please tell how to pad 0's while transforming the matrix for unequal rows or columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks..! @Pragnesh Vitthani I just modified your answer.

```
var array = [[1,2,3],
             [4,5,6],
             [7,8,9,10],
             [11,12,13],
             [14,15,16]]

var transposedArray = [[Int]]

for i in stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: 1)
{
    var subArray = [Int]()
    for j in stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: 1)
    {
        if array[j].count < array.count
        {
            array[j].append(0)
        }
        subArray.append(array[j][i])
    }
    transposedArray.append(subArray )
}
print(transposedArray)
```

Comment: What is the difference to Pragnesh Vitthani's answer?

Comment: @MartinR I was getting IndexOutOfBounds exception. But now I want to be Equal, before transposing it. I don't get the desired output by using the above answers since array element length in array2 is greater than number of array elements.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an implementation that does what you want:

```
func transpose(_ input: [[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {
    let columns = input.count
    let rows = input.reduce(0) { max($0, $1.count) }

    var result: [[Int]] = []

    for row in 0 ..< rows {
        result.append([])
        for col in 0 ..< columns {
            if row < input[col].count {
                result[row].append(input[col][row])
            } else {
                result[row].append(0)
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Or, alternatively:

```
func transpose(_ input: [[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {
    let columns = input.count
    let rows = input.reduce(0) { max($0, $1.count) }

    return (0 ..< rows).reduce(into: []) { result, row in
        result.append((0 ..< columns).reduce(into: []) { result, column in
            result.append(row < input[column].count ? input[column][row] : 0)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**Swift 3**

```
var array = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14]]
var arraytrans = [[Int]]()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: 1)
    {
        var subArray = [Int]()
        for j in stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: 1)
        {
            if array[i].count < array.count
            {
                array[i].append(0)
            }
            subArray.append(array[j][i])
        }
        arraytrans.append(subArray)
    }
    print(self.arraytrans) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic version based on @Rob's solution:

```
func transpose<T>(_ input: [[T]], defaultValue: T) -> [[T]] {
    let columns = input.count
    let rows = input.reduce(0) { max($0, $1.count) }

    return (0 ..< rows).reduce(into: []) { result, row in
        result.append((0 ..< columns).reduce(into: []) { result, column in
            result.append(row < input[column].count ? input[column][row] : defaultValue)
        })
    }
}
```

Usage: call `transpose(srings, defaultValue: "")` or `transpose(integers, defaultValue: 0)`.