# Why does array indexing in Swift not return an optional value?

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, swift4

When accessing a dictionary, such as `[String: Any]`, the result type is `Optional(Any)`.

When indexing an array of `[Any]`, the result type is `Any`, and the call can throw a fatal error.

Is there any reason for this difference?

It would be so nice to branch execution with a `guard let`, `if let`, `?`, and `??`, but instead you have to wrap array indexing in an `if data.count <= index`.

Comment: If you know the size of the array then you know that all index values from 0 to size - 1 will return a value/object so making this optional would be weird in my opinion. A dictionary doesn’t have this well defined range so it’s not comparable

Comment: *the call can throw an IndexError.*. No, it cannot `throw`, it raises an exception. An out-of-range exception cannot be caught with `try - catch`.

Comment: @vadian You're right. Some python snuck into the question there. Edited.

Comment: Most likely the reason is the Objective-C compatibility.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that is actually a good point. There would be no other way to check if a key exists other than going for it.

Comment: Compare [Safe (bounds-checked) array lookup in Swift, through optional bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25329186/1187415).

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for that link. My follow up question was definitely how to implement the prior. Is it possible to achieve the same functionality without the parameter name (e.g. array[safe: index] becomes array[index])?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson But it does have a "well defined set" (a range is just particular kind of set, with contiguous members), so I think that's a moot point.

Comment: @RolfLocher: Theoretically yes: You can define a `subscript (index: Index) -> Element?` method, but then you have to call it as `let b: Int? = a[0]` or `let b = a[0] as Int?` so that the compiler can distinguish the methods  from the context. I would not recommend that. – Actually I would  not use a “safe subscript” at all. As said above, you always know which indices are valid. A failure might indicate a logic error in your code.

Comment: @MartinR I did not consider that, thanks for the clarification. As an aside, surely accessing a dictionary with a nonexistent key would be just as much of a logic error, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's ultimately for performance reasons:

> ## Commonly Rejected Changes
>
> ...
>
> ### Strings, Characters, and Collection Types
>
> - Make `Array<T>` subscript access return `T?` or `T!` instead of `T`: The current array behavior is [intentional](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151214/002446.html), as it accurately reflects the fact that out-of-bounds array access is a logic error.  Changing the current behavior would slow `Array` accesses to an unacceptable degree. This topic has come up [multiple](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151214/002425.html) times before but is very unlikely to be accepted.

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/commonly_proposed.md#strings-characters-and-collection-types

Though nothing stops you from rolling your own:

```
extension Collection {
    subscript(safelyIndex i: Index) -> Element? {
        get {
            guard self.indices.contains(i) else { return nil }
            return self[i]
        }
    }
}

let array = Array(0...10)
let n = array[safelyIndex: 3]
print(n as Any) // => Optional(3)
```