# Iterating For In Loop In Swift Using Parse Server

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, parse-server

I have a chat  filled with users and of course a username array. I want to get the profile picture associated with the username in order for each user in the username array. Parse, however, can only sort by ascending/descending order that I am aware of.

Therefore, I need to figure out how to sort the data once received.
I am ultimately appending a url to be used as the pic.

```
    func getPics(_ completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    
    var dictionary: [String : Int] = [:]
    var unit = 0
    for username in usernameArray {
        unit += 1
        dictionary[username] = unit
    }
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
    if let objects = objects {
        for object in objects {
                if error == nil {
                    for user in self.usernameArray {
                    let pfuser = object["username"] as! String
                    if pfuser == user {
                    let imageFile = object["profilePic"] as? PFFileObject
                    let imageFileString = imageFile?.url as! String
                    if let url = URL(string: imageFileString) {
                        let replacedImageUrlString = imageFileString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[removed for privacy]", with: "removed for privacy")
                        let url = replacedImageUrlString as NSString
                        self.urlArray.append(url)
                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
        }
                     completionHandler()
                }
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of Parse server, So I dont really know if there exists provision to get the response in specific order, if it exists that should be the optimal solution. But there is a generic issue with your solution, its the **time complexity**.
You have two nested for loops which makes its **worst case complexity** to be **O(n^2)**, I guess the least you can do is to reduce its complexity to **O(n)**

```
func getPics(_ completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")

    var dictionary: [String : Int] = [:]
    var unit = 0
    for username in usernameArray {
        unit += 1
        dictionary[username] = unit
    }
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
        if let objects = objects, error == nil {
            let objectsDict = Dictionary(grouping: objects, by: { $0["username"] as! String /* typically you should be accessing $0.username, but again am not aware of  PFObject */})
            for user in self.usernameArray {
                if let pfuser = objectsDict[user]?[safe: 0] as? PFObject {
                    let imageFile = pfuser["profilePic"] as? PFFileObject
                    let imageFileString = imageFile?.url as! String
                    if let url = URL(string: imageFileString) {
                        let replacedImageUrlString = imageFileString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[removed for privacy]", with: "removed for privacy")
                        let url = replacedImageUrlString as NSString
                        self.urlArray.append(url)
                    }
                }
            }
            completionHandler()
        }
    })
}
```

Once you get the array of `PFObject`, you can create a dictionary with username as the key and PFObject as value, once you have the dictionary you can get the `PFObject` for specific username in **O(1)**, so you can run a single for loop which reduces your code's complexity to **O(n)**

**P.S** If you are wondering what `[safe: 0]` is you can add this handy extension to safely access object at specific index in an array

link: [Safe (bounds-checked) array lookup in Swift, through optional bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329186/safe-bounds-checked-array-lookup-in-swift-through-optional-bindings)

```
extension Collection {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

**P.P.S:** My answer is completely ignoring the complexity of `Dictionary(grouping:` API itself, I tried to look for the info, but couldnt find. But I think its **O(n)** not really sure though, whatever it is if its not **O(n^2)** you will still be benefited