# Swift: array[0] vs array.first. Why they behawe differently?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I have **ScrollView** in **LazyVGrid**. Inside there is **forEach** cycle create views that appear. User can create new item in this scrollView. When new view is created using ScrollViewReader I observe change of custom Bool property that toggled and scroll view to top using

```
.onChange(of: boolProperty) { _ in
                    withAnimation {
                        reader.scrollTo(viewModel.items.[0].id, anchor: .top)
                    }
                }
```

and everything works fine, but if i change `[0]` to `.first` like this

```
.onChange(of: boolProperty) { _ in
                    withAnimation {
                        reader.scrollTo(viewModel.items.first?.id, anchor: .top)
                    }
                }
```

behavior isn't the same and view scrolls only a little bit and not to the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`first`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/first) returns an optional type (returns nil when the array is empty), so `viewModel.items.first?.id` is of type `ID?`, where `ID` is the type of `id`.

On the other hand, `viewModel.items.[0].id` is of the non-optional type `ID`. The subscript returns a non-optional type, and crashes when the array is empty.

`scrollTo` scrolls to a view in the scroll view, that has the id you specified. Your views probably has *non-optional* IDs, so passing a value of an optional type will never match any view you have, and therefore doesn't scroll to the desired view.

Comment: Small addition, just to be on the very safe side: when using `items[0]` you should wrap the code in `if !items.isEmpty { ... }`. Using `.first` (as it's an Optional) will make sure the code will not crash. If you blindly get `items[0]`, your app will crash if the items array is empty.

Comment: What JanMensch could be extended to any index really, for example you could define `extension Array { func element(at index: Index) -> Element? { indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil } }` or similar. An actual `Element` if the index exists, or `nil` if it doesn't, effectively working similar to `first`, `last`, etc.

Comment: Or using a subscript like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30593673/1986221).

Answer (score 1):

It's different, `items[0].id` is non-optinal, that's, i.e, an `Int`. And `items.first?.id` is opposite, `Optional<Int>`. Basically, it won't match that's why scroll does not work. Try this:

```swift
withAnimation {
    if let firstID = viewModel.items.first?.id {
        reader.scrollTo(firstID, anchor: .top)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, solution works but i was looking to more clarifying answer like answer above from Sweeper

Comment: It's ok, you got the idea.