# searchbar color ios 11

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am trying to change the color of my search bar the problem is when I do the cancel button loses its color and I am unable to see it. If you have any ideas please let me know. Thank you!

Code:

```
self.searchController = UISearchController.init(searchResultsController: searchDataSource)
self.searchController?.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
self.searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
self.searchController?.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
self.searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for items"
self.searchController?.searchBar.isTranslucent = false
self.searchController?.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
self.searchController?.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

Comment: check this answer [UISearchBar cancel button color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15791136/6689101)

Comment: @zombie that did it! Thank you for your help!